# Fail to open ports on AWS using security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here is my security group attached with EC2 instance :

[Aws Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO0KP.png)

If I launch a service listening on port 80, 8080, 8888 it's working, but fail on 9000, 9042, 9999.

I don't find any documentation with this limitation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Source must be 0.0.0.0/32

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing rule and add below rules to your security group to make it working.(Provided your application is properly serving in these ports)

Rule 1: TCP , 9000, 0.0.0.0/0

Rule 2: TCP , 9042, 0.0.0.0/0

Rule 3: TCP , 9999, 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Sorry if I don't make be clear but I try to open all port to a public IP. I also tried to open specific port as your answer without success.

Comment: Can you check the output of below command when your application is configured for port 9000. `sudo netstat -anp |grep 9000`

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            :::*                    LISTEN      32119/java`

Comment: Guess you did netstat with port 9042. Thats fine. Does the process id 32119 belong to your service? Also please let me know what url you are using to access your service?

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solution

I am presuming the source is your ip/the ip of your company.

You should always [set your security group to be as specific as possible](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A5-Security_Misconfiguration).
In this case you should have the following inbound rules:

*8.8.8.8/32 is placeholder for your ip*

```
TCP 80 8.8.8.8/32

TCP 8080 8.8.8.8/32

TCP 8888 8.8.8.8/32

TCP 9000 8.8.8.8/32

TCP 9042 8.8.8.8/32

TCP 9999 8.8.8.8/32
```

Make sure the instance/application is listening on the needed ports etc.

Also make sure the application(s) on 9000,9042,9999 are not trying to reach anything upon receiving a request and are unable to (either because of sg outbound limitations or connection issues). Try determining what goes wrong based on the [error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) you get when trying to connect (based on ports I am assuming http traffic).

#### Clarification on your question

There are (as far as i can tell) no limitations on sg's in the context you give. I use groups with the same rule and groups with 20 rules without issues.

[There are limitation on the amount of groups and/or rules.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups)